# EXCEL IF STATEMENT AND ISNUMBER SEARCH

Tags: excel, if-statement, search

I am basically trying to have multiple ISNUMBER and IF statement:

```
**DESCRIPTION        CATEGORY**

ALL ACCESS    --    NA  
AMTRAK NRT    --    TRAVEL  
INDEED        --     Recruting
```

So basically. if the word has "all" put NA, if the word has "amtrak" put travel, if the word has "indeed" put "recruiting"

I'm trying with this

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("amtrak",D9)),D9,"train"), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("all",D9)),D9,"t")
```

But it's not working. IT keeps give me error "value" or I tried this one

```
=IF((AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("abm",B5)),B5,"don't know")),AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("all",B5)),B5,"don't k"))
```

with same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest your `IF statements`:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("amtrak",D9)),"train", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("all",D9)),"na",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("indeed",D9)),"recruiting","")))
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! You saved me! I've been going crazy for hours.